# restangular post return value is undefined

Tags: post, angularjs, return, restangular

I use restangular to create albums,

```
createAlbum:function(obj){
            albumlist.post(obj.data).then(function(res){
                console.log(res)
                obj.success(res)
            },function(err){
                obj.error(err)
            })
        }
```

and I call the service like this

```
$scope.createAlbum = function(){
    albumService.createAlbum({
        data:$scope.newalbum,
        success:function(data){
            $scope.albumlist.push(data)
        },
        error:function(err){
            alert('error'+err.status)
        }
    })
}
```

but after the album successfully posted the console.log(res) always undefined , any thing wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Check the network tab to see if your POST request is actually returning something. If it's not, then that's the issue :).

Otherwise it should log something.